# NPRUNTIME plugin not loading in chrome,works fine with FF-3.6

Tags: plugins, google-chrome, npapi, npruntime

I have modified my existing code to support npruntime to be used with FF-3.6 and above.
It loads and works perfectly fine with firefox 3.6 and above but chrome is not able to load the plugin (though its able to detect plugin) and gives "Missing Plugin" error. 
anyone having clue about what can be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that it can detect the plugin, do you mean it shows up in chrome://plugins? If so, is the MIME type you expect listed under its details?

The missing plugin error can show up if the plugin crashes during initialization, in addition to showing up if no plugin is found at all, so if everything looks right in chrome://plugins the next step would be to attach with a debugger during plugin initialization using the `--plugin-startup-dialog` flag.

Comment: i got this thing working removing all xpcom related stuff from my code...its now working in chrome...but safari is still an issue..my plugin isn't detected by safari :(